# onKeyDown is not called after updating support library

Tags: android, android-support-library

Recently I have updated android support library to version 22.1.0

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
```

I am overriding method onKeyDown and found that it is not called after updating library. If I go back to previous version of library it works fine.

Is there any other method to override in new support library version if user presses key.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Which button you are trying to intercept? Can you post your `onKeyDown`? are you using `ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Which button you are trying to intercept? Can you post your `onKeyDown`?

Comment: on menu button edited answer and added code.

Comment: onKeyDown is not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this solution, it's not the best, but i think this is the only that could work.

In the onCreate method of your Activity add these lines:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        Field mDelegateField = AppCompatActivity.class.getDeclaredField("mDelegate");
        mDelegateField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mDelegate = mDelegateField.get(this);

        Field mWindowField = mDelegate.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mWindow");
        mWindowField.setAccessible(true);
        Window mWindow = (Window) mWindowField.get(mDelegate);

        Window.Callback mOriginalWindowCallback = mWindow.getCallback();
        mWindow.setCallback(new AppCompatWindowCallbackCustom(mOriginalWindowCallback));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Create this class inside the class of your activity:

```
private class AppCompatWindowCallbackCustom extends WindowCallbackWrapper {

    public AppCompatWindowCallbackCustom(Window.Callback wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        final int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        final int action = event.getAction();

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // do your stuff
        }

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: this might work no problem in doing that but onKeyDown has to work after all Activity is parent of AppCompatActivity as well isn't it a issue in support library.

Comment: AppCompatActivity intercept menu button to open the option menu, you can see it [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/7cc23e31790b02f31707b36655401a69b8e6ebc2/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java#L730) . For this reason you didn't receive the event. The only option is to override dispatchKeyEvent as you can see in the answer.

Comment: its not calling dispatchKeyEvent

Comment: its working if my activity extends Activity instead AppCompatActivity there is some issue with support library I guess.

Comment: Yes, i just checked and unfortunately with `AppCompatActivity` this method don't work anymore because dispatchKeyEvent is hidden by `AppCompatDelegateImplBase`

Comment: This is funny what if some one wants to handle key events, is there any other way to do this.

Comment: I just updated my answer, now it will works with 22.1.0. Please take a look

Comment: I guess this is bug onKeyDown should work will report this issue and will accept this answer if issue is not fixed.

Comment: i don't think this is a bug, the code of AppCompatActivity is straightforward, it is a desired behavior. If you want to intecept the menu button this is the only way

Comment: Thanks for the help but I dont think its desired behavior support libraries are to support backward compatibility. OnKeyDown is very prime method and it should be called.

Comment: Only the KEYCODE_MENU is intercepted by the v7 support library. The other keys work as expected and onKeyDown is properly triggered

Comment: keyDown is not triggered for menu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76177/discussion-between-apk-and-mattia).